# Method that takes two different objects

Tags: c#, .net, object

So i have two different objects, with different properties:

```
public class ModelA : IServices
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; } (Enum)
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public int Limit { get; set; }
        public int ChargePower { get; set; }
    }

public class ModelB : IServices
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; } (Enum)
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public int Power { get; set; }
    }
```

I have then created an Interface:

```
public interface IServices
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

And i then use this interface as a input parameter on my method:

```
public async Task EditObject(IServices serviceObject)
        {
           
        }
```

My problem now is that if i call the method with e.g ModelA, i can only use the properties that is inside my Interface, and yes that makes sense.
How can i make a method that can take both ModelA and ModelB and access the different properties inside these two objects?
Is generics the way to go? or do i have to make two different methods? or am i on the correct way with an Interface?
For instance i dont want ModelA to have ModelB:s property e.g "public int Power { get; set; }"
Hope you understand my question, cheers!

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you want to access the remaining properties of ModelA and ModelB, and for what purpose? The point of interfaces is precisely that the properties and methods in the interface are all you care about in that method.

Comment: You could just create two overloads for each type and put any common code in a separate method that they both call using the interface.

Comment: @MKloster Sure, so the method is a repo method i will update these different properties on a SQL Server table. So i will determine on "ServiceType" which properties that i will update.

Answer (score 0):

You can test, which class is it:

```
if (serviceObject is ModelA)
    ((ModelA)serviceObject).Limit = 5;
```

Or you can use Reflection:

```
PropertyInfo pi;    
if ((pi = x.GetType().GetProperty("Limit")) != null)
    pi.SetValue(x, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, **a lot of ways**

You can make a method overload

```
public async Task EditObject(ModelA serviceObject) { }
public async Task EditObject(ModelB serviceObject) { }
```

or you could access needed type through upcasting it

```
var iServiceVariable = (IServices)new ModelA();
var modelBVariable = iServiceVariable as ModelB;
Console.WriteLine($"Is iServiceVariable of ModelB type? {modelBVariable != null}");
```

[image]

Or you could implement different behavior in your models using the same interface(doesn't have to be IServices), but accessing them in EditObject through the same way (what's the point of interface otherwise?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do different things for multiple types, a fairly clean way to do it is by using a switch on the type:

```
switch(serviceObject)
{
    case ModelA modelA:
        modelA.Limit = 5;
        break;
    case ModelB modelB:
        modelB.Power = 2;
        break;
}
```